# ASP.NET_SessionId cookie value does not allow multiple logins to the same web application from the same pc

Tags: asp.net, security, session, cookies

We have a web application running on ASP.NET 3.5. It is viewed by the world as one URL but in reality there are multiple IIS boxes hosting the application controlled by a load balancer.

My problem is that it is a sensitive application with strict security controls around it, and that post authentication if you open another browser to the same application and log in as someone else, the second login overwrites the first logins' session id value in the cookie, and then the first window crashes.

Any idea how I can get around this?

Comment: By "another browser" I assume you actually mean "another instance of the same browser"? I doubt this would happen if you open IE and FireFox.

Comment: Usually if you visit a site from another tab or instance of the same browser, while logged in, it detects this and doesn't give you the option to login with a different account.

Comment: yeah, thats a point. it should be difficult to even get to a login page if you open a second browser ...

Comment: A web browser's session are tied to the browser instance, not each tab,new windows..etc.  You should have one auth ticket per browser instance.  That is just how the web works.  Anything else is a hack.

Comment: _rick,

You are correct, but the problem is that each tab essentially ends up using the same session then, and then server side if one session logs out and we do a session.clear() and session.abandon(), all other instances are null.

Answer (score 2):

The session ID is placed in the cookie. If another browser window is opened and starts a second session the ID in the cookie will be replaced.

Also, logins should not be controlled via the session cookie. There is a Forms Authentication cookie for that purpose which is more secure as I recall.

Comment: "The session ID is placed in the cookie. If another browser window is opened and starts a second session the ID in the cookie will be replaced." - This is exactly my problem, as for the Forms Authentication cookie, we have our own authentication server, and really cannot replace this in any easy manner.

Comment: A separate authentication server does not disbar you from using Forms Authentication. They still have to type their authentication details in a web page somewhere on your site?

Comment: Or are you saying the other server authenticates the user then passes them to your site? (Like OpenID?)

Comment: No, our site does the authentication, and stores all of it in a SQL database. The problem is that according to MS, by default they allow up to 20 different cookies per site on a pc, but we find that it only uses 1 and that causes heaps of grief for us.

Comment: But the session cookie will always be named the same (so that ASP.NET knows which cookie holds the session ID), hence the clash.

Answer (score 1):

Most web applications only allow one session per PC. Try logging into Yahoo Mail, Amazon or Ebay twice on the same machine and you will find the same problem. So ASP.NET is pretty much designed around the idea that there is one login per PC. Although, if you have multiple browsers installed on a machine, you can generally log into apps more than once because each browser keeps its own cookie collection.

edit: You might want to try [cookieless sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx), in theory they might allow multiple sessions per PC, although I haven't tried it. But cookieless sessions come with plenty of problems and limitations of their own.

In short, there may be some hacky way to do what you want to do, but it will probably be fiddly and cause other problems elsewhere, because what you are asking for goes against the grain of ASP.NET's core design.